# Characters in string replacement. clean(dna)

Tags: python, replace

In data analytics, it is very common for data to come to us in a dirty form, with errors related to how it was transcribed or downloaded. Since we know any sequence of dna must consist of the four bases `'a'`, `'g'`, `'t'`, `'c'`, any other letters appearing in dna must be a mistake. Write a function `clean(dna)` that returns a new DNA string in which every character that is not an A, C, G, or T is replaced with an N. For example, `clean('goat')` should return the string `'gnat'`. You can assume dna is all lowercase, but don't assume anything about the nature of the wrong characters (e.g. they could even have been accidentally transcribed as numbers).

```
clean('') → ''
clean('agct7ttczttctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctxtgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtcygatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgcc') → 'agctnttcnttctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctntgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtcngatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgcc'
clean('gtgagtaaattaaaattttnttgacttaggtcactaaptactttaaccaatataggbatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtac') → 'gtgagtaaattaaaattttnttgacttaggtcactaantactttaaccaatataggnatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtac'
```

Using for loop

No import

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: What is your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not doing your school work for you.
I see an answer has already been posted using .sub, but you asked for only for loops to be used

```
def clean(text):
    cleaned_text=""
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if text[i] in "agtc":
            cleaned_text=cleaned_text+text[i]
        else:
            cleaned_text=cleaned_text+"n"
    return cleaned_text

print(clean("agct7ttczttctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctxtgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtcygatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgcc"))
# returns agctnttcnttctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctntgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtcngatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgcc
```

Comment: "not an A, C, G, or T is replaced with an N"

Comment: I have fixed it now, it is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks! I was developing a code for this problem and got stuck. Didn't add the else statement smh. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Side note: you could simplify a bit with "if text[i] in "agtc":`

Comment: good idea! I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub`:

```
Import re
dna = 'gtgagtaaattaaaattttnttgacttaggtcactaaptactttaaccaatataggbatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtac'
dna = re.sub(r'[^ACTG]','N',dna.upper())
print(dna)
```

Comment: "Using for loop No import"